# How do I change CSS style for specific area of a WordPress page?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a WordPress page that displays the team members of a WordPress site. The team members have been added using the Team area of WordPress.

I have a large gap right before the last team member is added. This is due to the style.css `.teamsetheight` height being too many pixels. I can't set the pixels to a smaller number because that boundary also works for the other team members.

What I need to do is set the div class of a specific area in the page's html in the page to refer to a new `.teamsetheight1`. I don't appear to see any php pages in the editor that pertain to the page, but I do have a page in the "Pages" section of WordPress. Below is the text inputted on the Page section (text area)to show the team members.

I looked up showpost, but I'm still a little in the dark of how this works. Anyways,

my question is how can I modify the div classes in the page's html, or what other solution could solve my gap problem?

```
[team_list title="Meet Our Team:" showpost="6"]
```

Comment: A link to your page would make things a lot easier.

Comment: http://avantirecruiters.com/about/

Comment: If you look at `.teamsetheight` you will notice that it has a fixed height of `880px` this means that each team member "card" will always be `880px` high no matter how long the description for the member is.

Comment: I know it would be nice to override that some how for a specific team memeber

Comment: Which team member do you want to override?

Comment: Well Barbara. Since it appears that the large gap comes from the div class surrounding her info.

Comment: what about `.teamsheight:last-of-type` or `.teamsheight:nth-child(n)` ?

Comment: I just tried nth-child and I couldn't get it to work, but that is basically the solution I'm looking for since I have access to the css

Comment: I tried this:        .teamsetheight:nth-child(3) {
 height:600px;
}

Comment: This is a botched up way of doing this...rearrange the members to this order evelyn / rita / serena / barbara / christina and try this CSS `.teamsetheight {
    height: auto;
}`

Comment: What do you mean by arrange? I actually did set the height to auto and it's much better on the mobile version. It pretty much cleaned up any gaps as well on the desktop Chrome version too.

Answer (score 0):

As I think possible solution is 
you can show maximum 3 lines  of team member info . and  readmore button..
and you can set teamsetheight 450px for all team member .